# primefaces dialog not showing up

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

Hi guys primefaces' dialog box not showing up anymore. Here is my code. Please help, did I do something wrong.
this is code where I call dialog box from column titled 'More':

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="holder">
    ...
    <p:column>  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="More"/>  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <p:commandLink value="more" type="button" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" actionListener="#{editCustomerView.viewCustomerInfo}" update=":content_form:customerInfoDialog" oncomplete="_cusInfoDlg.show()">
                        <f:attribute name="currentCustomer" value="#{holder}"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
    ...
    </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>

//dialog is here

    <p:dialog id="customerInfoDialog" widgetVar="_cusInfoDlg" header="Зээлдэгчийн мэдээлэл">
            <ui:include src="#{editCustomerView.infoPage}.xhtml"/>
            <h:commandButton value="ok" styleClass="btn" style="width: 100px; float: right; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;" onclick="customerInfoDlg.hide(); return false;"/>
    </p:dialog>
```

Here is backing bean actionListener method

```
public void viewCustomerInfo(ActionEvent event)
{   
    this.currentCustomer = (Customer) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("currentCustomer");
    this.currentCustomerAddress = prepareCurrentCustomerAddress(this.currentCustomer);

    if(this.currentCustomer.isIsCitizen()){ 

        this.infoPage = "CitizenInfo";


    }
    else
    {
        this.infoPage = "OrganizationInfo";
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by adding dynamic = 'true' to dialog. But why is it solved this way?

Comment: if you remove the `type="button"` from your `<p:commandLink` you will be able to get rid of the `dynamic = 'true'` from your dialog, am I right ?

Comment: have you migrated from an older version to a newer one?

Answer (score 0):

I usually open dialogs via Javascript

```
    PF('_cusInfoDlg').show();
```

Comment: Please clarify WHY you do it this way, since in the example of the OP it is also opened via javascript in the oncomplete!!!